# why nginx performs better than apache httpd server?

Tags: linux, apache, select, nginx, epoll

we discuss the problem on Linux.

I aways heart that nginx performs better than apache httpd server.

But apache works in the mode each cpu core has one process which has one thread. correspondly, nginx has master and worker.when a http request(via tcp) comes to web server,apache begine to process it ,when finish it,process the next one this process fetched.Like this, nginx should do the same thing:process one request,and then another.

how can nginx performs better than apache? I wonder.

Does the  term  or concept ‘concurrent quantity’ really means something about performance?

Virgin ask here -:)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, it depends on the task and how requests generated(dynamic vs. static). Both server implementations have their own advantages and disadvantages. This post can shed more light on that: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/apache-vs-nginx-practical-considerations

Comment: In the case of static http resource request,do you mean file io make the difference between them?